# Remote debugging(NOT localhost) tomcat using eclipse. Connection refused from remote machine

Tags: java, tomcat, remote-debugging, jdwp

I have started tomcat with jpda option in a remote machine(not localhost). I was not able to access the port. It throws a connection refused. I was able to do this in localhost successfully. Then why not from a remote machine. I am using tomcat 9.X and ubuntu 16.04 and java 8

Edit 1:
 The JDWP port 8000 listens only to 127.0.0.1. Is it possible to change this?
[image]

Comment: Test the tcp port: Follow these steps to test a TCP connection with telnet

Open a command prompt
Use the following Syntax:
telnet <Destination IP> <port number> Does it work?

Comment: telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: I have also allowed  port 8000 in UFW. netstat shows port is used by java application. I am able access the application

Comment: Could you check this link:https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/enable-remote-debugging.html. Looks for me useful.

Answer (score 12):

Finally, I found the issue. By default Catalina.sh(Tomcat script) binds only to localhost. If you want to access from another machine, then do

```
export JPDA_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8000
sh catalina.sh jpda start
```

0.0.0.0 allows from all the interfaces. You can also configure to one IP.

Another working solution is to do ssh tunnel from the remote machine to debugger machine.

```
ssh -L 8000:localhost:8000 user@remotemachine
```

If you still face any issues, then check the firewall. In ubuntu you can do it using UFW(Uncomplicated firewall)

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw allow 8000
```